# Difference between BSMTP and and simply forwarding an MX-record?

Tags: email, smtp, mx-record

I am trying to understand the benefits of BSMTP, but must admit I do not quite understand the concept of it.

- What are the main differences between BSMTP and simply forwarding an MX-record?
- What is the difference between BSMTP and having a fallback MX?
- Are there any downsides to using BSMTP?

Hopefully you can clear this up for me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

BSMTP can refer to a few different things, I'm guessing you're not referring to any of the daemons named that.

On the protocol side it comes in most commonly as "batched SMTP" and is only relevant for hosts that don't have a regular connection and for whatever reason can't rely on standard queueing behaviour.

You could be referring to TURN/ETRN support, which is just a simple way to prod a backup MX that the primary is back.

Some people seem to use it to mean "backup SMTP" which is either just a low priority MX, or something that I've not seen any definition for.

The short answer is a fallback MX is what most people expect to see.